# Approaches for Content-based Item Recommendations

Tags: cluster-analysis, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering, collective-intelligence

I'm currently developing an application where I want to group similar items. Items (like  videos) can be created by users and also their attributes can be altered or extended later (like  new tags). Instead of relying on users' preferences as most collaborative filtering mechanisms do, I want to compare item similarity based on the items' attributes (like similar length, similar colors, similar set of tags, etc.). The computation is necessary for two main purposes: Suggesting `x` similar items for a given item and for clustering into groups of similar items.

My application so far is follows an asynchronous design and I want to decouple this clustering component as far as possible. The creation of new items or the addition of new attributes for an existing item will be advertised by publishing events the component can then consume.

Computations can be provided best-effort and "snapshotted", which means that I'm okay with the best result possible at a given point in time, although result quality will eventually increase.

So I am now searching for appropriate algorithms to compute both similar items and clusters. At important constraint is scalability. Initially the application has to handle a few thousand items, but later million items might be possible as well. Of course, computations will then be executed on additional nodes, but the algorithm itself should scale. It would also be nice if the algorithm supports some kind of incremental mode on partial changes of the data.

My initial thought of comparing each item with each other and storing the numerical similarity sounds a little bit crude. Also, it requires `n*(n-1)/2` entries for storing all similarities and any change or new item will eventually cause `n` similarity computations.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE tl;dr**

To clarify what I want, here is my targeted scenario:

- User generate entries (think of documents)
- User edit entry meta data (think of tags)

And here is what my system should provide:

- List of similar entries to a given item as recommendation
- Clusters of similar entries

Both calculations should be based on:

- The meta data/attributes of entries (i.e. usage of similar tags)
- Thus, the distance of two entries using appropriate metrics
- *NOT based on user votings, preferences or actions* (unlike collaborative filtering). Although users may create entries and change attributes, the computation should only take into account the items and their attributes, and not the users associated with (just like a system where only items and no users exist).

Ideally, the algorithm should support:

- permanent changes of attributes of an entry
- incrementally compute similar entries/clusters on changes
- scale
- something better than a simple distance table, if possible (because of the O(n²) space complexity)

Comment: maybe it is helpfull to replace the term "similar" with a masurement how distant are two aspects of the items beeing compared and sum these. OverallDistance = lengthdistance + colordistance + tagsdistance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing from scratch take a look at mahout.apache.org. It has the clustering algorithms you are looking for as well as the recommendation algorithms. It works alongside [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop), so you can [scale it out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability#Horizontal_and_vertical_scaling) easily.

What this will allow you to do is determine similar documents in a cluster based on your keywords and/or description of the video.

https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/k-means-clustering.html

has a quick tutorial about clustering of documents using a [Reuters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reuters_Group) dataset. It is quite similar to what you are trying to achieve. Mahout includes recommendation algorithms such as slope one, user based, item based and is incredibly easy to extend. It also has some pretty useful clustering algorithms which support dimension reduction features. This is useful for you in case your matrix is sparse (that is, a lot of tags that have very few usage stats).

Also take a look at [Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene) to use its tfidf features to cluster tags and documents. Also check [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Solr). Both are Apache projects.

Answer (score 3):

[Recommendation Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323768/how-does-the-amazon-recommendation-feature-work) would be very helpful as it lists standard algorithm for dealing with your purpose.

Updated:

I guess what you are looking at is [Collaborative Quality Filtering](http://maya.cs.depaul.edu/webkdd04/final/traupman.pdf) and not only Collaborative Filtering, I have attached link to paper, hope this helps.

Comment: As far as I understood it, these algorithms are all based on user ratings or similarities.

Comment: They are also taking into account product specifications. Once user selects a particular product then according to the product type other relevant recommendations are made.

Comment: OK, which algorithm are you referring to? Amazon does item-item computations, but only on subsets that are generated from user behaviour, and not on every item compared to every other item from the whole set.

Comment: Yes, you are right but can you elaborate little more as to what exactly are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: I still think these are different kind of things. Collaborative Quality Filtering is using weighted reviews (votes/ranks etc.). I don't have any reviews at all.

Comment: Ok. How is tagging done on the items ? And who is responsible for tagging ?

Comment: Tags can be added to items by any user. An existing tag can be up- or downvoted by all others. This might be a starting point for adapting the Amazon algorithm (grouping by tags instead of purchases). But I also want to compute similarity using other values like the creation time and other numeric similarity values.

Answer (score 3):

[K-means clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) may be what you want.

N.B.:

> The number of clusters k is an input parameter: an inappropriate choice of k may yield poor results ... It works very well on some data sets, while failing miserably on others.

So you should consider how many clusters, how many tags, and what metric.

See also Stack Overflow [questions/tagged/k-means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/k-means).

Answer (score 2):

http://taste.sourceforge.net/old.html

> Taste is a flexible, fast
>   collaborative filtering engine for
>   Java. The engine takes users'
>   preferences for items ("tastes") and
>   returns estimated preferences for
>   other items. For example, a site that
>   sells books or CDs could easily use
>   Taste to figure out, from past
>   purchase data, which CDs a customer
>   might be interested in listening to.
>
> Taste provides a rich set of
>   components from which you can
>   construct a customized recommender
>   system from a selection of algorithms.
>   Taste is designed to be
>   enterprise-ready; it's designed for
>   performance, scalability and
>   flexibility. It supports a standard
>   EJB interface for J2EE-based
>   applications, but Taste is not just
>   for Java; it can be run as an external
>   server which exposes recommendation
>   logic to your application via web
>   services and HTTP.

http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/cofi/

> Currently, programmers who want to use
>   collaborative filtering have to  read
>   the literature and implement their own
>   algorithms. More often than  not,
>   programmers probably design their own
>   algorithms and they will  generally
>   produce suboptimal algorithms. We want
>   to build a foundation  of already
>   tested algorithms and documented that
>   can be used in a wide  range of
>   contexts from research to
>   applications.  The guiding principle
>   is that the design should be thin.
>   Cofi doesn't want  to be all things
>   for all people. So the focus is on
>   delivering very few lines  of code,
>   and to rely on the programmer for
>   providing the necessary glue.

Few more [here](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-collaborative-filter-in-java)

Comment: Note that "Taste" has long since been rolled into Apache Mahout.

Answer (score 1):

Before starting to implement, adapt or use existing library, make sure you know the domain; reading something like "[Collective Intelligence in Action](http://www.manning.com/alag/)" is a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You want an item-based collaborative filtering rather than user-based. There are a number of algorithms for this floating around on Google. Item-based solutions always scale better than user-based solutions. *[Item based collaborative filtering in PHP](http://www.codediesel.com/php/item-based-collaborative-filtering-php/)* has some easy-to-follow example code and fits what you're looking for:

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what the similarity metric is based on the specifics of your product and your good sense. Is length of video important? If so it deserves high weight.