# Designing a product recommendation

Tags: data-mining

I was searching for product recommendation system in shopping carts and saw, [How does the Amazon Recommendation feature work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323768/how-does-the-amazon-recommendation-feature-work)
and in many other sites there are several complex solutions were given and each method has some disadvantage in adoptation.  Instead of using complex methods, is it not very easy to get user feedback like giving options for the users to choose why they ordered a particular product. Example, if a user purchases a book, he will be given options, 1)author 2) genre 3)price 4)publisher.  By this system, one can get the exact reason for the sale of the product.  Are there any disadvantages in implementing this method?  Thanks

Comment: Could not understand for down votes. My question was very specific. Anthoy-Mousse answer was the answer i was looking for and the answer he gave was not too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Users do no want extra interactions.

There is a reason why "one click shopping" is successful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Click

Most likely, they will be annoyed and not come to your site anymore, and prefer an online retailer that doesn't ask them this extra question. They may also just click random buttons to make the window go away, without caring. **What is the incentive for them to answer correctly?**

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, this was the answer i was looking.